# How to know current location of file before save it?

Tags: filesystems, memory

I am using windows OS. Suppose I were open a notepad in windows and then type something in it but do not save it.
So I want to know that what is current location of notepad file before saving it means where it is currently present like in Ram, Rom or in Cache memory or in hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

By "location of file" you can refer to one of the following things:

- **logical location on disk**, i.e., in which directory and subdirectory the file is. You can see this by asking the application itself, usually there will be a "Properties" dialog, or by selecting "Save As..." instead of "Save". The former will propose a default saving folder that, *for most applications*, in this case would be the location of the existing file... provided it exists, i.e., it has already been saved at least once.
- **physical location on disk**, i.e., which sectors in the magnetic media hold the data the file is made out of. There are several disk editors that do this, designed to recover lost files. The physical location is attached to the file's *metadata* and is mapped in a description area (or several areas) reserved for that purpose on the file system. In Windows NTFS you have the Master File Table (MFT).
- **logical location in memory**, i.e., what memory structure holds your file. The computer memory is divided in several areas, some only accessible to the OS's kernel, some accessible to high level users, some accessible to everyone. Your file should "live" in the *heap* of the *address space* of the Notepad application, which itself lives in *userspace*. To know *where* in the heap, you need a debugger to open Notepad and follow its internal memory pointers.
- **physical location in memory**, i.e., where exactly the above spaces lie in the physical memory. If they are there at all. Logical memory is not necessarily in RAM; modern processors may "swap" portions of precious RAM, deemed unused or not sufficiently used, to disk or other device, thereby freeing said fast and precious RAM for the use of some needier application. Those applications that find themselves swapped out are not aware of this, because the physical-to-logical information is usually hidden from them by the kernel. This way, you as an application might "see" 64 GB of RAM, on a computer with only 4 GB of RAM.

The "clipboard" is another memory area altogether, it is owned by the OS (actually I think by Windows Explorer, i.e. by the User Interface which lies above the OS - but I'm not too sure), and is **not** available to Notepad to store a "file". It can be used by Notepad to store the file's *content* for a time: Select All, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> and now your file's content is in the Clipboard, and you can *paste* it somewhere else. But the *file* is still on disk, and its memory representation is in Notepad's heap.

The ROM is Read Only Memory - it is written ("flashed") probably only once when the computer is assembled, even if some programmable ROMs (PROMs) can be re-flashed later with an appropriate program designed specifically for those ROMs. As such, *you* (or Notepad) can't store *anything* in a ROM.

The Cache memory is a very fast, hence very expensive, hence very small memory that is designed to keep handy whatever data the CPU uses most frequently. When you run Notepad and open a file, parts of that file, and parts of Notepad's code, will enter the CPU cache (or caches; there may be up to three levels, L1, L2, L3 - L1 is fastest, therefore most expensive, therefore smallest. But even L3 is usually faster than common RAM) and stay there for a while. Cache inspection is hard, since the program doing so needs to be executed by the same CPU that is using that very cache memory. It would be a bit like performing brain surgery on yourself.

Another meaning of the word "Cache" is to indicate a block of otherwise unused physical RAM that stores data after it has been read from the disk, as well as data that's meant to be written to disk, before actually doing so. This way, repeated reads do not "hit" the slower disk, and go faster; and writes can be done all together, in an order more suitable to the disk's data organization, and delayed until the system isn't so busy. These effects together combine to make the disk appear much faster than it really is. So, after reading a file in Notepad, that file will surely live *also* in the RAM disk cache for some time, unless and until that space is reprioritized and reclaimed for other uses.

Your file is or might "be" then here, depending on the meaning of "be":

```
DISK             [MFT]---->[You]--->[r f]-->
                 -->[ile]     [Your fi]-->[le (previous version)]
                       |     [Y]--[our file (deleted copy, space not yet reclaimed)]
                       |
                       V
INTERNAL DISK     [You][r f][ile]
CACHE                  |
                       V
MEMORY CACHE           [r f][ile][...other stuff...]

NOTEPAD'S HEAP    [Yo]--[fi]--[ur]--[le] [Yo] [other data] [undo buffer: Yrou]

CLIPBOARD         "This is my file's first sentence, which I just copied"

CPU CACHE         [first sent][...other programs' stuff...][just cop]
```

Comment: @Iserni Hey thanks for reply. Ya you are right that Copy,cut and undo redo related data go to clipboard but i don't think clipboard is owned by OS. So I still not get my answer about where is clipboard exist in computer system ? Or we can ask this question in another way that where is data or text is saved after cut or copy ? Still waiting for better answer

Comment: This is a *different question*. You never asked about clipboard: you asked about Notepad. The "clipboard" is usually owned by the *window manager* (WM), the application (so, above the OS) responsible for herding the various application windows. Its data are on the WM's heap. The various apps access it through specialized calls ("Could I cut something?" "What format is the clipboard in, currently? Image, text...?"). **Undo** data is a different matter again, and are the responsibility of each *application*, that undoes in its own way, even if some key presses such as Ctrl-Z are widely adopted.

Answer (score 1):

**You may utilize any standard debugging tool such as WinDBG or Olly Debugger in order to achieve this.**

You basically attach the debugger program to notepad and it then allows you to see the program in-execution along with the memory locations it utilizes, their values, registers and other resources.

Please refer to the following URLs to get started on the same:-

- http://www.theprogrammer.org/software/ollydebugger.php
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Durve-Decode141 I am not want to go in depth. I am just want to know the location of file in my computer system. My teacher said that the location of file is in Clipboard. I don't know it's right or wrong. If it is right can your please tell me the location of clipboard in computer system. Where is clipboard exists? Thanks for answer to this question.

Comment: @Androiddeveloper: You either misunderstood, or your teacher is wrong, or you're working on a *really* weird computer. I tried a comprehensive answer. Probably TL;DR, but still.

Comment: @Iserni I believe your answer is a perfect theorotical explaination, but I think he was after something much more basic. xD Upvoting.

Comment: You're most probably right, but I couldn't fathom the meaning of 'location' as given by the teacher. A friend of mine contributed this gem: "**Your file is wherever the heck your operating and file systems decide it's gonna be**" (which, I repeat, does *not* usually include *clipboards* :-) )

Comment: That's pretty damn accurate.

Comment: (funny - I could *swear* I had upvoted your answer yesterday, since I thought it likely to be useful to someone with a similar problem but wanting to go deeper. Retrying :-) )